# django development server with facebook connect

Tags: django, facebook

What URL should i give facebook to get a FACEBOOK_API_KEY if i'm using facebook connect with the django development server?  I understand I need to edit my local host, but i'm not sure with what.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 2):

The correct course is to not change your local /etc/host, but to use "http://localhost/" as your Facebook Connect Redirect URL.  It is literally what Facebook returns to you, and if you're doing development locally, it's what you want.

Ideally, you want two FB application registrations: One for PRODUCTION, and one for DEVELOPMENT.  That way both continue to work correctly without interfering with each other.  (And maybe a third for BETA (or Staging, or Testing, or whatever you want to call it.))